# Joomla how to create list of products with prices in store

Tags: joomla

In Joomla I have web page with stores. Each store is article. And now I want to create list of products with prices in these stores. Each product can be article too. But I must assign this product - article to store - article? And how to assign price to product - article ?

Comment: Can products be in many stores?  How many stores are you talking about and also do you need to be able to search based on price? Or just display price?

Comment: Yes each products can be in many stores like common products. Stores can be a lot of - now about 200

Comment: Are you asking this a programming question or as a site administrator question? Are you actually selling things or just showing a catalog? I think you might be better off using one of the ecommerce extensions that is designed for this.  There are probably ways to do what you want in core Joomla, maybe using tags and an extra field for price but you will quickly find that it is a lot more complex than that (e.g. taxes, sales, multiple orders)

Comment: I need only price field for product and thats all. My site is not ecommerce site. It is simple web site with products and prices, and that's all

Comment: You can add a field to the product articles with a plugin.   I think the problem you have is the many to many relationship of stores to products.  It might work to make each store a tag (these can be just like articles in terms of how they look) and then tag the products with the stores that carry them. Otherwise, I think in the normal context you are going to end up with a lot of duplicate product articles. Or you could add more url fields to the store articles and use those to link to the product articles.